# create array of structure that has no default constructor

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ Object array initialization without default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754763/c-object-array-initialization-without-default-constructor)

I have structure:

```
struct aa 
{
    int a;
    char  b [255];

    aa(int number)
    {
        cout<<"creating structure "<<number<<"\n";

    }

    ~aa()
    {
        cout<<"destroying structure"; 
    }
};
```

I'm trying to create array of this structure, but this doesn't work:

```
aa *ss = new aa[3](1);
```

This gives me a compiler error.

How do I do it?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. But the answer is probably, "don't use arrays, use some sane collection like a vector".

Comment: I think it's fairly clear what the question should have been. I've edited the post to add the implied question.

Comment: You should use use `std::vector<aa>`. If you can't for some reason, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2493450/59379) covers the alternatives.

Comment: Yeas, I know about vector, but I'm trying to understand language specific. I have feeling that nobody uses simple arrays even in simple applications - is it true?

Comment: Some use them to do really simple things.

Answer (score 0):

```
aa(int number=1)
・・・
aa *ss = new aa[3];
```

or

```
template <int N>
struct aa
・・・
aa(int number = N)
・・・
aa<1> *ss = new aa<1>[3];
```

or

```
#include <new>
・・・
aa(int number=0)
・・・

int main(){
    aa ss[3];//local value
    for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
        new (ss + i) aa(1);//replacement
```